# generate a pdf in wordpress without using the plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am a wordpress developer. I am stuck here with I need to generate a pdf in wordpress without plugin so just let me know how?

```
<div class="abccenter">
    <button class="red_bt margin40">Download PDF</button>
</div>

<div class="abcpostwrapper margintop20">
    <div class="abcpostcontent">
```

on this download button?

Comment: You might need to provide a little more detail before someone can help out. What sort of content are you trying to put in a PDF? Does it need special formatting, or just plain text? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It looks like php has an extensive set of functions for PDF creation, outlined here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create pdf via MPDF (http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) with simple integeration.